# How to extract changes from WPF RichTextBox's TextChangedEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using a WPF RichTextBox and I'd like to synchronize it with another RichTextBox (in another window). What I'm trying to do is when a TextChanged event occurs I try to extract the user's change so here's what I tried (for insertion):

```
void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var change = e.Changes.FirstOrDefault();
    var s = sender as RichTextBox;

    var start = s.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset);
    var end = s.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(change.Offset + change.AddedLength);
    var range = new TextRange(start, end);
}
```

However the Offset and AddedLength values seemed a bit undeterministic. When I enter the first character Offset is 1 (I expected 0) and AddedLength is 3 (I expected 1) then at the second character Offset = 3 and AddedLength = 1. Also, when there are 5 characters, `s.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(3)` returns null. So all in all, I'm quite confused about how to get the content in question from the RichTextBox based on the event arguments. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.changes(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN that describes the properties of the **TextChangedEventArgs**. When the event occurs there might be multiple changes to the underlying format, so you need to process the provided collection of **e.Changes** entries one at a time from first to last.

You should not look at the caret position as this will not tell you what has happened to the underlying text. Again, this is explained in the provided link in more detail.

Comment: After reading the documentation I have a better understanding of this and I checked the plain text representation of the RichTextBox's FlowDocument but I still don't understand the Offset values and how I might extract the user's change (when typing characters 1 by 1, e.Changes.Count is always 1)